# Linux Mint : Wifi connecting but no internet access

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, dns

It doesn't say anywhere no internet access, but whenever I try to do anything that requires internet, it doesn't work.

`sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches` this fixes the wifi temporarily (for around five minutes) but rebooting or just using it as is for a few minutes and the issue resurfaces. When I was on windows this issue was still present but flushing it once fixed it permanently. The driver manager says everything is up to date.

System:

Kernel: 5.4.0-74-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 5.0.4 wm: muffin dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 20.2 Uma base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal

Machine:

Type: Laptop
System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP 15 Notebook PC

v: 0991100000000000000600087 serial:  Chassis: type: 10 serial:

Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 220D v: 86.52 serial:  UEFI: Insyde v: F.39
date: 05/26/2015

Battery:   ID-1: BAT1 charge: 0% condition: 39.9/39.9 Wh (100%) volts: 4.0/14.6

model: 13-42 OA04041 serial:

status: Charging

CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i3-4010U bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Haswell

```
       rev: 1 L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
       flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 13568

       Speed: 1696 MHz min/max: 800/1700 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1696 2: 1696 3: 1696

       4: 1697
```

Graphics:  Device-1: Intel Haswell-ULT

Integrated Graphics vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: i915

```
       v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:0a16
```

Device-2: NVIDIA GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M]

vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: nouveau v: kernel bus ID: 09:00.0 chip ID: 10de:1140
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa

resolution: 1366x768~60Hz

OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2) v: 4.5 Mesa 20.2.6

compat-v: 3.0 direct render: Yes

Audio: Device-1: Intel Haswell-ULT HD Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel

v: kernel bus ID: 00:03.0 chip ID: 8086:0a0c

Device-2: Intel 8 Series HD Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel

v: kernel bus ID: 00:1b.0 chip ID: 8086:9c20

Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-74-generic

Network:

Device-1: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet vendor: Hewlett-Packard

driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 4000 bus ID: 08:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:8136
IF: enp8s0 state: down mac:

Device-2: Ralink RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe vendor: Hewlett-Packard

driver: rt2800pci v: 2.3.0 port: 3000 bus ID: 0a:00.0 chip ID: 1814:3290

IF: wlp10s0f0 state: up mac:

Drives:    Local Storage: total: 689.33 GiB used: 8.62 GiB (1.3%)

ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: HP model: SSD S600 240GB size: 223.57 GiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s
serial:

ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: HGST (Hitachi) model: HTS545050A7E680 size: 465.76 GiB

speed: 6.0 Gb/s serial:

Partition:

ID-1: / size: 218.57 GiB used: 8.61 GiB (3.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
USB:       Hub: 1-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 2 rev: 2.0 chip ID: 1d6b:0002

Hub: 1-1:2 info: Intel ports: 8 rev: 2.0 chip ID: 8087:8000

Hub: 2-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 9 rev: 2.0 chip ID: 1d6b:0002

Hub: 3-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 4 rev: 3.0 chip ID: 1d6b:0003

Sensors:

System Temperatures: cpu: 47.0 C mobo: 47.0 C

Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A

Repos:     No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list

Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list

```
1: deb http: //packages.linuxmint.com uma main upstream import backport #id:linuxmint_main       
2: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse      
3: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse    
4: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse   
5: deb http: //security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse 
6: deb http: //archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ focal partner
```

Info:

Processes: 193 Uptime: 15m Memory: 3.78 GiB used: 1.25 GiB (33.0%) Init: systemd v: 245

runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 alt: 9 Client: Unknown python3.8 client inxi: 3.0.38

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:-**

The information is in there:-

Device-1: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet vendor: Hewlett-Packard
**driver: r8169** v: kernel port: 4000 bus ID: 08:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:8136 IF: **enp8s0** **state: down** mac:

Device-2: Ralink RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe vendor: Hewlett-Packard
**driver: rt2800pci** v: 2.3.0 port: 3000 bus ID: 0a:00.0 chip ID: 1814:3290
IF: **wlp10s0f0** **state: up** mac:

Explanation:- Your ethernet connection [enp8s0] is down, but your wifi connection [wlp10s0f0] is up.

Note:- considerable information about your system could have been safely omitted.

Since you have the fairly recent upgrade of Mint 20.2, you must have had a good internet connection to install/upgrade this.

Have you made any significant changes recently?

Comment: See a long comment, submitted as an answer.

Comment: The wifi worked for sometime when i installed but then it stopped working. Like i said , flushing dns cache makes it works for like five minutes before it stops working again. I haven't made any significant changes but i did to something along the lines of ifconfig (wifi device name) up.

Comment: If this was running the `ifconfig` command, with no parameters, then this just displays the state of your machine network ports and is quite safe - the more "modern" way is to use the `ip a` command. Fixing anything by flushing the DNS cache is a **probable** indication of faults external to your PC.

Comment: So what you're trying to say is that the issue is probably caused by the router/wifi incompatibility in some way with my laptop? That might actually be it as it works fine with mobile hotspots. I am from India , and the service provider i use is called Jiofiber, idk much about networking but could that help in determining what could be the issue?

Comment: Sounds like you need to contact your service provider.

Comment: Well i went back to windows and for the most part it's working fine? Like the connection does drop for a sec sometimes but it comes back up automatically.

Comment: Also , i am not sure what kind of problem is it on the isp side cuz other devices work fine. I'm sure there's some issue with the dns but it's probably device related. I just hope my wifi card hasn't stopped working completely. Anyways, what do you suspect could be the issue , if from the isp?